# Ubuntu Server 16.04 update fail?

Tags: apt, server, package-management, updates, update-manager

Recently installed  Ubuntu Server 16.04.6 LTS to run a headless home server.  In addition to base install  I have also installed Samba file sharing, OpenSSH and Plex Media Server.  I did not opt for auto security updates in the installation. All functions are running excellently with one exception- updates.

Immediately after clean/base install I ran apt-get update and apt-get upgrade from root and both executed properly.  Now when I run  apt-get update and apt-get upgrade my system polls the repositories and fetches updates (see output below).  But on the next boot/reboot it appears that the updates have not taken effect since the “available updates” report line shows the same data as before.

I’m new to running my own server so I suspect this is something simple that my lack of experience is causing, but can’t figure out the remedy.  Any ideas?

```
    Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-159-generic x86_64)

8 packages can be updated.
1 update is a security update.


Last login: Fri Aug 16 15:05:28 2019 from 127.0.0.1
xx@xxserver:~$ su
Password: 
root@xxserver:/home/xx# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]  
... (deleted intervening entries)                      
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [4,328 B]                         
Fetched 3,658 kB in 7s (491 kB/s)                                                                                     
Reading package lists... Done

root@xxserver:/home/xx# apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libdrm2 open-vm-tools ubuntu-minimal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
root@xxserver:/home/xx# 

---------------------------reboot--------------------------------------------------

Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-159-generic x86_64)

8 packages can be updated.
1 update is a security update.

New release '18.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.


Last login: Fri Aug 16 16:06:56 2019 from 127.0.0.1
xx@xxserver:~$
```

Comment: Classic new-user papercut: The login messages are not created in realtime, but are updated *daily*. The packages-to-be-updated numbers *were* accurate when the string was last updated...but are obviously inaccurate now. You can have have the system recalculate updates at every login, but it's unnecessary and would slow your startup. For folks who login daily or weekly, the numbers are much closer to accurate. Otherwise, just use it as a simple reminder to update/upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Probably not my last paper-cut, but I am enjoying venturing into another side of computing. Quick responses here are definitely encouraging.